# $scope.apply? $digest already in progress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Before you say it, yes I have looked at all the other links related to this issue, but none of them seem to apply to my situation.

I am relatively new to Ionic, and am seeking some help.

I have a controller,

```
.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCapture, VideoService) {

$scope.clip = '';

$scope.captureVideo = function() {
    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo().then(function(videoData) {
        VideoService.saveVideo(videoData).success(function(data) {
            $scope.clip = data;
            $scope.$apply();
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + data);
        });
    });
};
```

and a call to it,

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="captureVideo()">
        Capture a video
    </button>
</div>
```

That is supposed to update an image,

```
$scope.urlForClipThumb = function(clipUrl) {
    var name = clipUrl.substr(clipUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var trueOrigin = cordova.file.dataDirectory + name;
    var sliced = trueOrigin.slice(0, -4);
    return sliced + '.png';
}
```

That gets applied here on screen...

```
</div>
    <img ng-src="{{urlForClipThumb(clip) || '//:0'}}" ng-click="showClip(clip)" style="height: 250px; width: 150px;"/>
</div>
```

But, the image never updates, and the $scope.$apply(); always returns a digest in progress error?

Let me know if you need more information! (I've tried safe applies and timeouts and they wont do anything either...)

Comment: Why are you calling $scope.$apply(). You're not modifying scope from outside the digest loop. You're using angular event handlers. From what you showed, you don't need to call it.

Comment: So does `urlForClipThumb()` return proper values?

Comment: i think you have to remove $scope.$apply()

Comment: Thanks LPK lol? If I don't call $scope.$apply(), the image does not update, I dont know why all of a sudden, it has decided to start throwing this $digest error, it makes no sense. So, now with it or without it, the image does not update. urlForClipThumb() returns the proper location of the thumbnail. Not using $q. I guess, how do i update the {{urlForClipThumb(clip)}} so I can see my thumbnail... The image was appearing when I first created the project.

Answer (score 0):

If `VideoService.saveVideo` is using `$q` then it will call `digest`, so no need for `$apply` any more. You can check if digest is in progress and apply conditionally:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    scope.$digest();
}
```

Comment: its not.....  saveVideo: function(data) {
  starter(data[0].localURL);
  return promise;
 }

Comment: Yea none of these solutions work... Even when i link directly to the photo the ng-src does not update the view to the image